# trouble saving in Mongoose 3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update some content in Mongoose.js 3.1.2 and I can't get these two functions to work. Any ideas why? Thanks...

```
function(req, res) {
  Content.findById(req.body.content_id, function(err, content) {
    // add snippet to content.snippets
    content.snippets[req.body.snippet_name] = req.body.snippet_value;
      content.save(function(err) {
        res.json(err || content.snippets);
    });
  }
}


function(req, res) {
  Content.findById(req.body.content_id, function(err, content) {

      // delete snippets
      delete content.snippets[req.body.snippet_name];
      //content.snippets[req.body.snippet_name] = undefined; <-- doesn't work either

      content.save(function(err) {
        res.json(err || "SUCCESS");
      });

  });
}
```

My schema looks something like this:

```
contentSchema = new Schema(
  title: String,
  slug: String,
  body: String,
  snippets: Object
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may need to mark the paths as modified. Mongoose may not check the object properties since you didn't create an embedded schema for them.

```
function(req, res) {
  Content.findById(req.body.content_id, function(err, content) {
    // add snippet to content.snippets
    content.snippets[req.body.snippet_name] = req.body.snippet_value;
    content.markModified('snippets');  // make sure that Mongoose saves the field
      content.save(function(err) {
        res.json(err || content.snippets);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! How did I miss it. Thanks Bill